# I am currently developing a script in PERL it works but I would like to append the contents to the CSV file whenever the script is executed

Tags: postgresql, perl

```
print "Enter number of days: ";
my $var = <STDIN>;

my $SQL = "COPY (SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE StartDate < NOW() - INTERVAL '$var days')
           TO '/home/username/Desktop/new1.csv' WITH CSV";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
my $rv1 = $dbh->do($SQL) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: Currently, the contents of the csv file are replaced whenever the script is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs for the postgresql COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html), I don't see any obvious was to append to the file in postgresql. But with Perl, you could open the contents of one file and append it to another file, so you could do something like

```
my $SQL = "COPY (SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE StartDate < NOW() - INTERVAL '$var days')
           TO 'some_other_file.csv' WITH CSV";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
my $rv1 = $dbh->do($SQL) or die $DBI::errstr;

# append some_other_file.csv to ~/Desktop/new1.csv
open my $f1, '<', 'some_other_file.csv' or die "No other file: $!";
open my $f2, '>>', '/home/username/Desktop/new1.csv' or die "Can't append: $!";
print $f2 <$f1>;
close $f2;
close $f1;
unlink 'some_other_file.csv';
```